# Como integrar TinyMCE com ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, tinymce-4

Implementanto o `TinyMCE` em `ASP.NET MVC` encontrei um problema ao realizar *upload de imagens*.

A forma que estou tentadto implementar é a seguinte:

Tenho uma `View` com o `Script` que chama um `Controller` contendo um método de *upload* que faz seu trabalho salvando a imagem em meu servidor, como é um método comum e está funcionando perfeitamente, deixei ele no **[Gist](https://gist.github.com/Renancp01/efae5bdffd0328b12275b1ed21742750)**, afim de encurtar um pouco a pergunta. E a minha **`View`** :

```
@model EuVotoAf.Models.Publicacao

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";

}
<script src="~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.js"></script>
<h2>Create</h2>

<iframe id="form_target" name="form_target" style="display:none"></iframe>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Publicacao", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "my_form", target = "form_target", enctype = "multipart/form-data", style = "width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input name="file" type="file" onchange="$('#my_form').submit();this.value='';">
}


<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools"
        ],
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | ltr rtl",
        image_advtab: true,
        templates: [
            { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
            { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
        ],
        file_browser_callback: function (field_name, url, type, win) {
            if (type == 'image') $('#my_form input').click();
        }
    });
</script>

@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Conteudo, new { id = "my_editor", @class = "mceEditor" })

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Publicacao", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

O que preciso é basicamente, enviar o texto pra ser salvo no `DB` e a imagem pra ser salvo no servidor. Se eu colocar, a linha

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Conteudo, new { id = "my_editor", @class = "mceEditor" })
```

Dentro do primeiro `form` ele não renderiza na tela, se coloco no segundo, os o *upload* não é feito. Qual, é a forma que eu possa fazer pra que funcione de alguma forma.

Estou fazendo da forma errada?

Está certo, porem contem erros no código ?

Tem uma forma melhor de fazer ?

Caso tenha algum outro detalhe que seja importante que não inseri, posso colocar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não irei falar muito sobre o TinyMCE, e sim sobre seus problemas e uma forma **genérica** de resolver.

Primeiro, você possui dois `forms` na mesma página. Mesmo utilizando Ajax *indiretamente*, você poderá ter alguns problemas.

Outra coisa, não coloque `scripts` no meio da View. Você possui uma `section` somente para ela.

E o seu maior problema. O TinyMCE não está em nenhum `form`. Em resumo, ao enviar o formulário `@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Publicacao", FormMethod.Post))` o valor de `Conteudo` não será enviado.

Bom, agora vamos à solução **genérica**.

Primeiro, atualize sua View para isso:

```
<h2>Create</h2>


<input name="file" type="file" id="file">

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Publicacao", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Conteudo, new { id = "my_editor", @class = "mceEditor" })

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts{
    <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea",
            theme: "modern",
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
                "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools"
            ],
            toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
            toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | ltr rtl",
            image_advtab: true,
            templates: [
                { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
                { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
            ],
            file_browser_callback: function (field_name, url, type, win) {
                if (type == 'image') $('#my_form input').click();
            }
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $('#file').change(function () {
            var formData = new FormData();
            var file = this.files[0];
            console.log(file)
            formData.append('file', file);
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Upload", "Home")',  
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    tinyMCE.get('my_editor').setContent('dsdsdsds');
                    tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

E seu Controller para isso:

```
  public string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string path;
        string saveloc = "~/Uploads/Imagens";
        string filename = file.FileName;

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath(saveloc), Path.GetFileName(filename));
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "<script>alert('Failed: " + e + "');</script>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "<script>alert('Failed: Unkown Error. This form only accepts valid images.');</script>";
        }

        return @"<img src=/Uploads/Imagens/" + filename + " >";
    }
```

Note que agora eu estou fazendo o **Upload** no evento [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/).
Após isso, eu envio o arquivo para o Controller via Ajax e o retorno eu insiro no TinyMCE, através do `tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, data);`.

Note que o retorno do Controller não é mais um script, e sim uma imagem `return @"<img src=/Uploads/Imagens/" + filename + " >";`. Fiz desta forma pois se você alterar o **WYSIWYG**, o código poderá permanecer o mesmo.

Agora, se você deseja adicionar o upload no botão de **insert/edit image**, a coisa muda um pouco.